# Return array of values instead of array of objects from SQL query in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a SQL query in a Rails model that responds with an array of objects. And each object has an attribute called `points` with a value.

But its preferable for query to just return an array of `points` like `[10,15,5]` instead of `[object,object,object]` which requires then extracting the points out into another array to be useful.

**Model file**

```
LAST_3_SELECT = "
  SELECT
    (
      (data.ap / (data.apa * 1.0))
      +
      (data.vp / (data.vpa * 1.0))
    )
    / 2 * 1.5 * data.level
    AS points
  FROM data
  WHERE data.user_id = ?
  GROUP BY data.id
  ORDER BY data.created_at DESC
  LIMIT 3
"

def self.last_3(user_id)
  connection.select_all(sanitize_sql_array( [LAST_3_SELECT, user_id]), "last-3")
end
```

Is this possible to do in a query itself, or necessary to do in a method outside it?

I don't have much experience writing raw SQL queries into Rails methods so any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make an addiitional map call?

Comment: For `.map(&:points)`, it returned `NoMethodError (undefined method 'points' for {"points"=>2.4000000000000004}:Hash):`

Comment: Just do `.map{ |row| row["points"] }`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to get the points into an array

```
def self.last_3(user_id)
  connection.select_all(sanitize_sql_array( [LAST_3_SELECT, user_id]), "last-3").pluck(:points)
end
```

Here `points` is the column name to be *plucked*

Comment: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'pluck' for #<ActiveRecord::Result:...>)`

Comment: Instead of .pluck(:points) use .collect(&:points). This will get you the list of pints in array.

Comment: @pandaman, for the active record result, is this working, `result.first.points`

Comment: Rails4. Tried `.collect()` and ran into something like `NoMethodError (undefined method 'points' for {"points"=>...}:Hash)`. But was able to get it working using `.map`.